# Is there a shorter alternative to "server connection configuration"?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

I am trying to find a name for a variable that contains the hostname (node45.service.com), the port (9984) and the server name (US Salami Server) of a service I want to connect to and looks something like this

```
class server_connection_configuration
     string server_name
     string hostname
     integer port
```

At the moment it's called *server_connection_configuration*. Is there a shorter alternative for that? It must encompass that it is a set of parameters that are needed to connect to a server. I understand that the server name does not really fit here.

I can't use *server_connection* because this implies that this would be the object that models the connection (a handle). I also can't use *connection_configuration* because in that context other connections exist as well.

I don't want to use abbreviations because it would contradict [clean code principles](https://blog.goyello.com/2013/05/17/express-names-in-code-bad-vs-clean/).

**What word(s) could I use instead?**

*I tagged `single-word-requests` but maybe there is a better tag for this question.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for suggestions re the naming of programming variables and functions.

Comment: I don't see the problem, because I could rewrite the question to not have the variable but then it would be harder to answer imho. Yeah, it's a technical concept but the word could be used outside of programming as well imho.

Comment: Well, *you* try rewording the question so the expression you seek refers to some meaningful real-world concept outside your highly specific technical / programming context! If you can do that, I'll retract my closevote.

Comment: I actually think your name is clear enough as it is. Why not use it? It is a bit long, but not excessively so. (Unfortunately, asking for advice on naming things or variables is off topic on this site, sorry. The rules: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I will do so, if more people agree that this question is too programming specific and the question gets closed. Imho the mere fact that I am looking for a variable name does not make this question off-topic to this site. If I were to ask how I could name a variable for the number of people who live in a city, then that answer would include the word "inhabitant" and this word is not limited to being used in programming. Imho you are applying the rule without considering why it was probably introduced in the first place.

Comment: @problemofficer - if you believe the question is merely asking for an English word, you could rephrase the question to remove the programming context.  But in this case it seems like that context is important.  Variable naming is off-topic because it typically is very opinion-based.

Comment: Perhaps you could think of it as being a “resource locator” of sorts.

Comment: Why could you not call it "SCC"?

Do you truly believe anything like hostname (node45.service.com), the port (9984) or the server name (US Salami Server) of a service have significant meanings in English, as opposed to Arabic, French or Zulu?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't know, this is why I am asking. And afaik the English language has a lot of words for technological terms that others languages do not, because they were invented in the US.

Comment: Uh… what don't you know? Why can you not name your variable "SCC", or anything else you liked? There might be restrictions in a programming language you're using but why are there in English?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, hostname and port are combined with *scheme* to form a URL, so presumably you are using a library of some kind to send a message and receive a response. If so, the library will have some names to identify the parameters to be passed. It would be easiest just to use the library names.

For example, the Python *requests* package has a *get(url)* method where *url* is a string containing the scheme, hostname and port. In this case, you could call your class *url_params*.

Technically, if you have to provide a port number, your program is attempting to communicate with a program already listening on that port. So this can also give you a name.

Based on a quick Google search, port 9984 is associated informally with BigChainDB. There is probably a reference implementation of the BigChainDB client that can supply a name for your class. However, 9984 is not a well-known port, so maybe there is some other program. But the reasoning is the same.

If you want to use a class name that reflects the business logic as opposed to the implementation details, start with the word *address* and couple it with the business function being performed at that address.

Answer (score 0):

How about ‘server address’? Similar in idea to a house address of ‘number-street-town’.

You could somewhere early in the document define that ‘server address’ denotes the concatenation ‘servername-hostname-port’ and then always refer to it as ‘server address’.